# Matlab Kernel for Jupyter: conflict with python3.6 in anaconda

Tags: python, matlab, ipython, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to install the Matlab kernel for Jupyter Notebook in my conda environment, but I get the following error:

```
$conda install matlab_kernelFetching package metadata ...............
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - matlab_kernel -> pymatbridge -> python 3.4* -> xz 5.0.5
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

How can I solve this conflict?
Or also, how can I say anaconda to use python3.4 when I have to use the Matlab kernel?

I have tried to install it also via pip3 but i get also an error:

```
$ pip3 install --user matlab_kernel
 [...Downloading and unpacking]

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2482, in _dep_map
return self.__dep_map
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2344, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1266, in prepare_files
req_to_install.extras):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2291, in requires
dm = self._dep_map
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2484, in _dep_map
self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2508, in _compute_dependencies
parsed = next(parse_requirements(distvers))
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in parse_requirements
line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2583, in scan_list
"Expected ',' or end-of-list in",line,"at",line[p:]
ValueError: ("Expected ',' or end-of-list in", 'pytest ==3.2.*', 'at', '*')

Storing debug log for failure in /home/orco/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Create a new environment? `conda create -n matlabenv python=3.4 matlab_kernel`

Comment: The comment of @darthbirt worked, unfortunately the kernel crash continuously, but I think this is a problem of the kernel....